# "Прибытие на работу" и убытие с работы"

Tags: стилистика, недопустимая-метка

Можно ли говорить: "Прибытие на работу" и убытие с работы" (имеется в виду ежедневное)?

Answer (score 1):

Сдаётся мне, что официальное "прибытие" стилистически не сочетается со словом "работа".Прибытие сочетается со словами "поезда"(прибытие-отбытие), "к месту назначения", "к месту службы".
Убыть(выбыть) можно из состава чего-нибудь, убыть по болезни, убыть из полка. На работу люди приходят, потом уходят.Так что Инна права: только приход-уход. Во времена Андропова у нас на работе был журнал, где секретарь записывала: пришёл - в 7.40, ушёл - в 17.50.Что, здесь такая же надобность? Тогда пусть будет глагол, а не существительное, по крайней мере, по-человечески смотрится.

Comment: Скорее, не стилистически, а лексически (не сочетается), собственно по значению. Но тут, однако, типичная метонимия: работа = "место, где работают". Так что принципиального нарушения нет.

Comment: И лексически, конечно, но и стилистически:"прибытие" - это канцеляризм, а "работа" - нейтральное со сниженным оттенком. Если прибытие, то уж на место службы, на пост,на предприятие,на пропускной пункт, но не на работу.

Comment: Теперь понятно. *Работа* - действительно сниженное, но такое привычное, что сразу и не разглядишь.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, теоретически можно, но звучит криво. Я бы советовала, если уж нужен канцеляризм, сказать "отбытие с работы". Но лучше, конечно, было бы написать просто и по-русски: "уход с работы".

Comment: Тут важно, какая именно работа. Военные, насколько я знаю, именно *убывают из части* (не знаю, правда, ежедневно или нет).

Answer (score 0):

Это военный жаргон. В гражданских организациях - не стоит. 
Впрочем, военные тоже прибывают-убывают не на работу, а по месту службы или с него.

Answer (score 0):

А обязательны эти канцеляризмы? Просто "приход-уход" или "явка-уход" не подойдёт?

Comment: Только не явка. Это другой смысл.
А касательно канцеляризмов - так это смотря где такое используют. Если книга это, скажем, книга учета выдачи ключей от охраняемых помещений на режимном предприятии, то, может, оно и уместно.